# ORDER BY date joining in ascending and only show just the third one

Tags: sql-server

Also, I would like to include other information from the table, but show just this third one, choosing by the ascending joining order.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a very simple approach using SQL Server's `ROW_NUMBER` window function and a common table expression (CTE). These are two very useful tools to know and understand if you're new to writing T-SQL for SQL Server.

The CTE gathers an underlying resultset that can then be queried. In this case, we're requesting the third record only--achieved by the use of ROW_NUMBER and ORDERing BY OrderDate (defaults ascending).

```
;WITH Orders AS ( 
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY OrderDate ) AS OrderSeq,
        Customer,
        OrderDate
    FROM ( VALUES
        ( 'Fred Flintstone', '01/01/2020' ),
        ( 'Fred Flintstone', '02/01/2020' ),
        ( 'Fred Flintstone', '03/01/2020' ),
        ( 'Fred Flintstone', '04/01/2020' ),
        ( 'Fred Flintstone', '05/01/2020' ),
        ( 'Fred Flintstone', '06/01/2020' )
    ) o ( Customer, OrderDate )
)
SELECT
    *
FROM Orders WHERE OrderSeq = 3;
```

Returns

```
+----------+-----------------+------------+
| OrderSeq |    Customer     | OrderDate  |
+----------+-----------------+------------+
|        3 | Fred Flintstone | 03/01/2020 |
+----------+-----------------+------------+
```